# Supporting dynamic font for accessibility when UILabel and UIButton are side by side in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I have a UILabel and a UIButton which are placed side by side as per the attached screenshot.[image]

I am working on supporting dynamic font as part of accessibility. I put them in a stack view so that they could occupy equal spacing. I added the necessary code to support dynamic font and that works. The UILabel text moves to next line when it is short of space. However, button text did not roll into next line and cut off. So, I set no of lines to 0 for the button title label, defined a height constraint for the button and when the screen is launched, I read the height of the button title label and then change the height constraint of the button. This resized the button and the title rolled into next line when it is short of space. However, this works only for the initial launch. Code is as below.

```
contactSupportButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
contactSupportButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
contactSupportButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: regularFontSize)
supportButtonHeightConstraint.constant = self.contactSupportButton.titleLabel?.frame.size.height ?? 42
```

When the app is running, if I go to accessibility setting and increase  the system font size, I see that the button title font changes  but button height does not change appropriately based on the button title label font change though  I have the following method to update the button size when user changes system font size. Looks like button title label height is not right at this time.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    supportButtonHeightConstraint.constant = 
    self.contactSupportButton.titleLabel?.frame.size.height ?? 42
}
```

So, wondering why the button title label height is not correct here though it has the correct height which can be used to set button height when the screen is visited first time. Also, if there is a different way to handle this, I would like to know